# Change select2 auto selected tag when creating new tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I am using select2, I have it setup so I can create new tags if they do not exist.

This is all working fine, but one bug-bear I have is that the "new tag" is the automatically selected tag, this is causing a lot of bogus, accidentially created tags.

What I want is that the "new tag" shows at the top as it normally does,

But, if there are other sub-matching options, then the closest match there should be selected, the user can then press the up arrow if they wish to create a new tag.

This is what I want to appear when typing in "scrum" when the "scrums" tag already exists:

[image: optimal choice]

Answer (score 0):

I know that's old, but I came up to this question while searching for something else.

The default behavior of auto-selection is selecting the first matching option. Here, as far as I see "Scrum" comes before "Scrums" if sorting asc. That's why it selects "Scrum" (without 's' at the end). If the newly created option was "Scrumss", and no "Scrum" was in the options, then "Scrums" would be selected by auto-select.

I guess you figured your issue out, but didn't want to leave a question unanswered :)

Please write a comment if that is not the issue or I got you wrong.